# How to add @since when using PhpStorm

Tags: php, comments, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm and for functions I want to add `@since 1.0.0` in the comment section. Like this:

```
/**
 * some function name details
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
 function hard_choice(){
     return $blue_pill;
 }
```

There is no indication of how to get this in PhpStorm documentation.

- Has anyone used PhpStorm and got the `@since` to show up when doing [automatic comment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/creating-php-documentation-comments.html)?
- Can this be automated?
- Where do I specify a version number in PhpStorm that tracks this?

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the File and Code Templates for PHP Function Doc Comment:

[image]

This will insert the @since tag the moment you start a PHP-doc block before a written function (e.g., by typing `/**[enter]`)

```
/**
 * @return int
 * @since 0.1.0
 */
public function test() {
    return 1;
}
```